# SKSpriteNode.centerRect does not work with SKTextureAtlas

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm adding SKSpriteNode to my scene object using the following code.

```
  let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Ubiquity")
  let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: atlas.textureNamed("roundedBorder"))
  node.zPosition = 2000
  node.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0.4, y: 0, width: 0.2, height: 1)
  addChild(node)
```

After all, my texture looks distorted (please see attached image [wrong image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLTSk.png))
But, if I either remove `node.centerRect` setting or putting my image to xcasset directly the below way

```
  let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ubiquity-roundedBorder"))
  node.zPosition = 2000
  node.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0.4, y: 0, width: 0.2, height: 1)
  addChild(node)
```

everything works as expected (please see attached another image [correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaQdA.png))

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behaviour. This looks like a bug.